# API calls get canceled on page reload React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I have a situation where I want to log the time of user whenever reloads or closes a tab.

I have written the below code for the same.

```
useEffect(() => {
const cleanup = () => {
deleteAgentLoginDetails(`agentId=${userId.toUpperCase()}`);
agentLogout(`agentId=${userId.toUpperCase()}`);
>     };

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', cleanup);

return () => {
window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', cleanup);
>     };
[]);
```

My API call gets triggered but also gets canceled as soon as I reload the page.

Is there any alternate to achieve this?

Below is a screenshot of the network tab. (I have preserve logs enabled; that's why I can see the logs after refresh).

[network call screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE6M5.png)

Comment: To be clear you do NOT want the API calls cancelled?  Are you sure they are?  They might not be, you just might not see them cancelled since you are reloading.  Usually you have to explicitly cancel an inflight ajax call

Comment: yes, they are cancelled and i don't want them canceled in the edit i have pasted the screenshot of the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute server API call on beforeunload/ Limitations on page unload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60530716/execute-server-api-call-on-beforeunload-limitations-on-page-unload)

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60530716/execute-server-api-call-on-beforeunload-limitations-on-page-unload for a solution and https://css-tricks.com/send-an-http-request-on-page-exit/ for more information